# GlassFish, set context-path of webservice

Tags: web-services, glassfish, contextpath

I have EAR with my web-service. No war module in my application.
I mean
*http://[host]:[port]/*[context-path]/*MyWebService?wsdl*

For JBoss I am using `jboss.xml`
For WebLogic I am using `weblogic-webservices.xml`
What about GlassFish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this document says to [use the endpoint-address-uri to set the context-root for your web service on GlassFish](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/beasw.html)... That element would go into the glassfish-ejb-jar.xml file.